# Submit Form through href and passing Hidden variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am having a form, where I am listing all the messages. I also have a dropdown menu, to delete, archive, mark the message as junk. Here is the code snippet. I am doing a form submit through href attribute.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.inbox_form.submit();">Mark as read</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.inbox_form.submit();">Mark as unread</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.inbox_form.submit();">Move to Junk</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.inbox_form.submit();">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to differentiate between the four submits?

Answer (score 2):

Set the value of the dropdown before submitting. In the code below, I assume the name of the dropdown is `action`, replace it with the actual name, and replace the value string with an actual value:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.inbox_form.action.value='markread';document.inbox_form.submit();">Mark as read</a></li>
```

Comment: I donot have a dropdown, It is an unordered list. Do you think it is possible the set the value ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your suggestion. I do, now. I set a hidden value called "action" in the input_form

Comment: That was what I was originally going to suggest, then I reread the question where you said you have a dropdown menu, and thought you were talking about `<select>`.